# Start sections in an odd page only in one chapter

Tags: sectioning, chapters, books, book-design

I need to make all the sections of a certain chapter of my document (a book) appear in an odd page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have two solutions. The first one defines a new command `\mysection`; the second one automates the procedure thanks to `etoolbox`, but requires a conditional at the opening and one at the end of the chapter in which the sections must appear on an odd page. Here is a mwe:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% first solution
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{%
 \ifnum\value{section}=0\relax
  \else
   \cleardoublepage
  \fi
 \section{#1}}
\makeatother

% second solution
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newif\ifoddsections
\pretocmd{\section}{
 \ifoddsections 
 \ifnum\value{section}=0\relax
  \else
    \cleardoublepage
   \fi
 \else
\fi}{}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{With a new section command}
  \mysection{The first section of the chapter}\lipsum[1-6]
  \mysection{A section starting on an odd page}
  \mysection{A section starting on an odd page}
  
\chapter{With a conditional} 
\oddsectionstrue
  \section{The first section of the chapter}\lipsum[1-6]
  \section{A section starting on an odd page}
  \section{A section starting on an odd page}
\oddsectionsfalse

\chapter{A normal chapter with sections on even or odd pages}
  \section{The first section of the chapter}\lipsum[1-6]
  \section{A section starting on an odd page}
  \section{A section starting on an odd page}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think if you change your first version to end with `\fi\section}`, then you could drop the `[1]` argument and have it still work with `\section*`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.. some sections appear in an even page, despite using the conditional or \mysection

Comment: Ok, I did not fully understand your question... I edited my answer: now every section, except for the first, starts in an odd page.

Comment: @Ivan Thanks a lot, it works now! But for future people looking at this, I think you forgot to edit the title of your sections. Second and third should say "A section command on an odd page". And the first one I guess it depends of where the chapter starts.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the answer as suggested

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want the sections to start the page, and not start halfway down an odd page? If there's not too many sections, you could just put `\cleardoublepage` before all of them.  A higher level approach would be etoolbox's `\pretocmd{\section}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}`, appropriately localized.  But that might also run into trouble, since `\section` does some weird stuff.